# Getting NullPointerException during deserialization with Jackson when the array is empty

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I become *`Nullpointerexception`* using **Jackson**, trying to do deserialization, when there is an **empty array** inside nested objects.

### My Entites:

#### Person

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    //... 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "personWithMail")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "personWithMail")
    private List<MyMail> mailList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "employee")
    private List<Deploy> deploys;


}
```

#### MyMail:

```
@Entity
public class MyMail{
    //...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    private Person personWithMail;

}
```

#### Deploy

```
@Entity
public class Deploy{
    //...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "deploys")
    private Person employee;
```

### JSON Input:

This is the json data I try to send to the server and deserialize:
The output object should be an object containing a person and deploys.

```
{
    "aPersonOutsideDeploy":{
    //...
         "mailList":[] //No Error here
    },
   "deploys": [
        {
           //...
           "mailList":[] //ERROR. When I delete this line then the problem will be solved
        },
        //...
    ]

}
```

This is the error :

```
trace org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: my.com.tool.model.MYMODEL["deploys"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->my.com.tool.model.Deploy["employee"]->my.com.tool.model.Person["mailList"])
```

### What I have done so far:

On the stack trace you can find out that the error comes from this line in the library

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:341)
```

The problem is still there when you serialize an object and try to use the same json data to test deserialization. So the json input is not wrong.

Line 341: `if (valueDes.getObjectIdReader() != null)` and when you debug the app, `valueDes` is here null so it throws Nullpointerexception. I thought maybe the problem is with the library. I've created a custom deserializer, and inside, I return empty list when the input is `[]` and it works but I don't know it's the correct way to face this problem. Do you have any suggestion how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Which class instance is expected to be created as a result of the deserialization operation? Is it a Person? If so, the input JSON appears incorrect. Shouldn't the deploys attribute appear a level further down i.e., under employee?

```
{
   "mailList":[...],
   "deploys":[{
      "employee": {
         "mailList":[...],
         "deploys": [...]
      }
   }]
}
```

I suggest creating an instance of the structure in code and logging the serialized output to the console. Whatever JSON gets generated should deserialize to the intended class.

Comment: The end object is from another class called mymodel. And I've already created a json data with serialization and tried to deserialize the exact same data and the problem happens again.

Comment: It will be interesting to see the definition of mymodel class.
In the meantime, one thing that you could try though is initializing the List<> members to empty lists.